# Can't ping or connect to Raspberry Pi on same Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, ssh, raspbian-stretch, web-server, apache-httpd

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 web server connected to a Wi-Fi network and Windows 10 PC connected to that same network. From the PC, I cannot connect to the pi server or use SSH, however, if I connect the Pi to an ethernet cable, I can connect. Even worse, when using Wi-Fi instead of Ethernet, I can't even ping the Raspberry Pi from my PC. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH over wifi not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/62341/ssh-over-wifi-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue also, and it was related to my routers AP Isolation setting in the wireless WAN area.  Even though it was off, turning it on and back off fixed my issue.  AP Isolation is for allowing separation of "guests" to access the internet without exposing the rest of your internal subnet.

Answer (score 0):

The wifi interface will have a different IP address from the address of the LAN interface. Connect to the LAN interface and use `ip a` to show the address on the wlan interface.

Comment: I made sure to use the IP for wlan0 after unplugging the cable. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Connect a display to your Raspberry and try pinging the router on the WLAN.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the router from the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The run tcpdump on the wlan interface and see whether the ping from the PC arrives. If it doesn't, the problem is not on your PI.

Comment: tcpdump does show an output when I try to ping from my PC.

Comment: Append it to the question, together with the output from `ip a` and `ip r`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe silly, but I encountered this problem when I was connected to VPN... If that's the case, disconnecting from VPN should solve your problem.